# SSH: multiple entries for the same host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I would like to configure several credentials for the same host, with different user name and identity file. Currently the only way I know how to do this is by hacking around:

```
Host myhost
     User           user1
     HostName       myhost
     IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/user1.pem
     IdentitiesOnly yes

Host myhost-fake
     User           user2
     HostName       myhost
     IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/user2.pem
     IdentitiesOnly yes
```

This way I can:

```
ssh myhost
```

And:

```
ssh myhost-fake
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How else would ssh tell the entries apart?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe by keying by username, as in: `ssh user1@myhost` could automatically select the relevant configuration section keyed both by hostname **and** username. I do not know if there is any provision for such a usecase

Comment: What's wrong with the way you describe in your question? What would you consider better? What kind of improvement are you hoping for?